# rebase feature branch - but commit ids had changed

Tags: git, git-rebase

Starting point:

```
Dev: A -- B -- C
Feat:            \ -- D
```

Then pulled some new commits to `Dev`:

```
Dev: A -- B -- C -- NEW
Feat:            \ -- D
```

Then accidentally caused commits hashes on `Dev` to change* (and `push`ed with`--force`)
Uppercase and lowercase letters refer to the same patches - but commit hash are different:

```
Dev: a -- b -- c -- NEW
Feat:  A -- B -- C -- D
```

Now I want to `rebase` `Feat` from `Dev`, but the same patches are recognized as different commits, and `rebase` starts from `A` instead of `D`:

```
behavior: a -- b -- c -- NEW -- A -- B -- C -- D
expected: a -- b -- c -- NEW -- D (and recognize that A and a are actually the same)
```

Please help!!!

*Maybe you can tell me how to change them back: I ran an interactive `rebase` on Dev in order to only change commit messages with the `r` option. Then I realized that commit hashes changed, So I `reset` back - before the interactive rebase using `reflog`. But now commit messages are the old ones, but commit hashes are still different!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use `cherry-pick` instead of `rebase`

Revert the changes on dev (From where you want to rebase, the NEW changes).

```
git reset --hard <last NEW changes commit>
```

Sync with your remote dev with your local dev branch

Now `cherry-pick` the commits from feature branch and apply to dev

```
git cherry-pick <commit-ids from feat branch> //commit ids seprate with space
```

Comment: but I want the NEW changes to exist **before** the feature changes in history.

Comment: yes. You sync your local dev with remote/dev up to NEW  (recent change) then `cherry-pick`. Your feature branch changes will come after the NEW changes

Answer (score 0):

How did you rebase exactly, on what branch and with which command?

What you can do is rebase your feature branch against dev while you are on the feat branch with

```
git rebase master
```

It should work as expected.

If everything is broken, you can use `git reflog`. It will show you a list of events that happened on your local repository. Copy the hash of the event before your mistake, and then run

```
git reset --hard <reglog-sha>
```

It will reset everything at that point of history

Answer (score 0):

You could probably:

1. create a patch of the new changes you have done in branch 'feat'
2. delete 'feat' branch
3. create a new 'feat' branch from 'dev'
4. apply the patch from step 1 on the new 'feat' branch
5. force push new 'feat' branch

Now, you will now have 'feat' branch changes over 'dev'

For example, if there is only one commit on 'feat' below commands should work
(It works for n commits as well. You need to apply those many patches on the new branch)

```
git checkout feat
git format-path HEAD~1
git branch -D feat
git checkout dev
git checkout -b feat
git am -3 patch-file-created-using-format-patch
git push -f origin feat
```

Comment: what if I have a few commits on feat branch - could I still do this and retain the commit history?

Comment: yes. if there are n commits, do `git format-path HEAD~n`. It will create n patch files. apply them in order.